# REST - What is standard file format for RESTful API design?

Tags: rest

I would like to have my design stored as file for version control.

Are there any standards or commonly used formats?

For example, I can write one file for structure definition:

```
User {
  uid,
  name
}
```

And another file for API definition:

```
GET /users/:uid => User
GET /users?name=:name => [User]
```

However, these are in my own preferences. Are there any commonly used formats for representing these?

I expect it to be something like `UML`, regardless of language, just focusing on API itself.

Comment: A common pattern that many companies used to design rest api is like the one done by Microsoft and you can see the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation you mention is quite close to what developers would expect to get as a design or specification, so that might be enough.

However, if your project will get certain scale you can try to use some notation that might be then used by tools to automate either code generation, testing or documentation.

In particular, Swagger is a quite common tool to use for this. If you write your specification following these standards you'll get documentation and even some code generation if you use that tool.

https://swagger.io/specification/